# Finding whether duplicates exists in 2 select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Could you please help me with SQL statement to find duplicate names present in first Select statement and the second.

For example :
I need to find whether student with same name in Class 1 is present or not in Class 2 or 3.

```
select firstname from College where classid = 1
```

and Second select statement is :

```
select firstname from College where classid in (2, 3)
```

If there is matching occurrences for any name then I want to select that record.

Comment: [EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can be used. (sql-server) or [EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) for MySQL

Comment: @Luuk could you please answer with the code? thanks

Comment: You will need to add some table structures as any answer probably won't answer your (homework) question, as I doubt a college actually has a first name. And look up how to use the Exists clause.

Comment: @Arrow: the, very simple!, examples are on the links in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join could be one option

```
select a.firstname
from
(
select firstname from College where classid = 1
)a join (
select firstname from College where classid in(2,3)
)b on a.firstname=b.firstname
```

OR alternatively, you can try using `exists`

```
select firstname from College c where classid = 1
and exists (select 1 from College c1 where c.firstname=c1.firstname and classid in(2,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sum the count of existence for each set (`classid=1` vs. `classid in (2,3)`) by using `GROUP BY` expression with `HAVING` clause such as

```
SELECT firstname
  FROM College 
 GROUP BY firstname
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN classid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN classid IN (2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

`firstname` values are duplicated among each set whenever the both results returning from each aggregation are greater than zero.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=78b9cbd255d033212318f0ee7ae01b77)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

A very simple set-based method is to use `intersect`:

```
select firstname
from College
where classid = 1
intersect
select firstname
from College
where classid in (2, 3);
```